# How to have a menu accelerator with plus or minus signs in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, menuitem, shortcut

I have tried setting the accelerator of a `JMenuItem` using the following :

```
item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
```

The menu item shows the shortcut `⌘+` (on a mac) but hitting these two keys won't trigger it. I have the same problem with the minus sign `-`.

Is there any way to have a menu item with any of these signs as a shortcut ?

EDIT - Here is a SSCCE :

```
public class MenuWithPlus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("View");
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Zoom in");
        item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("ZOOM IN TRIGGERED");
            }
        });
        menu.add(item);
        bar.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have code (e.g. an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)) for us to play with?

Comment: worksforme - on windows vista with german keyboard layout and the plus/minus outside the num block

Comment: Are you using the `+`/`-` keys on the main keyboard vs. the numpad? They're seen as separate keys, so make sure you're using them consistently.

Answer (score 2):

At accelerator code you have to modify to:

```
item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ADD, Event.CTRL_MASK));
```

A test that I made was add a key event listener on frame and catch de key value for plus (in this case ADD).

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
    }
    });
```

Comment: When I listen to the key pressed event, I get a VK_SLASH event for my = (and shifted +) key... this is probably because of my french keyboard. Do you think there is a universal workaround for this ?

Comment: With the code below you can get the keyboard layout, then you create a method to map the key you need. InputContext.getInstance().getLocale()

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> keys on the main keyboard vs. the numpad? They're seen as separate keys, so make sure you're using them consistently.

I *think* `VK_PLUS` is not used for the usual plus key (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> on a US keyboard), but rather either the numpad <kbd>+</kbd>, or the <kbd>+</kbd> key on some German keyboards. Assuming you have a US keyboard, you might want <kbd>Shift</kbd> together with `VK_EQUALS`.

See [this old bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4262044) and [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/browse_thread/thread/8f88857137f225d2).

Comment: My dream (but it seems less and less possible to me) is that the user be able to trigger it with the main keyboard, but this causes problems since every keyboard has its own layout for the + and - keys (eg on my french keyboard, the - key triggers a VK_EQUALS event, and the equals (with shifted plus) triggers a VK_SLASH event...). Do you think there is a universal workaround for this ?